# C# flatfile foreach

Tags: c#

Hi I am creating a flatfile for something and wondered how I can get a values in a foreach string? So I want to get every [value] below is an example of my flat file...

```
[value][secret]secret_here[/secret][hello]hello_here[/hello][/value][value][secret]secret_here_new[/secret][hello]hello?[/hello][/value]
```

So it would get 2.. first one: `[value][secret]secret_here[/secret][hello]hello_here[/hello][/value]`

and the second one would be `[value][secret]secret_here_new[/secret][hello]hello?[/hello][/value]`

Is there any simple script for this? reading it from a file...

Comment: What is the point to mimic XML thus try re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

[Replace [] with <> tags in the string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .. And use [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401280/read-a-xml-from-a-string-and-get-some-fields-problems-reading-xml) to get values.