# Count how many times there is a specific text in a string and get the values in a array

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this XML file which I am having troubles deserializing it, so I'm going kind of way around it. I have an XML string and I want to get a value out of it. Let's say this is my XML string:

```
string XMLstring = "<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<InputText>123</InputText>
<InputText>Apple</InputText>
<InputText>John</InputText>
</note>";
```

Now, I have tried something like checking if the XMLstring contains InputText, but I want someway to get all the three values from there and then use them somewhere. Is there any way I can do this without having to deserialize it?

Comment: "without having to deserialize it" I don't see how that's possible. If you want to find the elements you're interested in, and obtain the contents of said elements, you need to parse the XML.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a XML (from a string) and get some fields - Problems reading XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401280/read-a-xml-from-a-string-and-get-some-fields-problems-reading-xml). How are you reading this file, if you are, I just see a hard coded string?

Comment: Another thing you could do is convert your XML String to JSON and then proceed.

Comment: Pretty easy: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sIUuV2

Comment: @Fildor Might want to double check that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ-to-XML to parse the string and obtain the values.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public static void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body><InputText>123</InputText><InputText>Apple</InputText><InputText>John</InputText></note>";
        
    var list = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("InputText").Select( x => x.Value );
    foreach (var item in list) Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
123
Apple
John
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tzlmy0)

Comment: It turned out that I had a corrupted XML string, strange symbols and stuff... Thank you very much for ur help.